# Separating Data model from View Model

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have an approach in designing MVC components which is to separate the Data Model (DB persistence) from the View Model of my component despite they represent theoretically the same element. I just map later the two models.

Do you think it's a good approach? Or I should try to make only one model?

Answer (score 0):

When I run into issues like this, I try to create only the necessary classes that I need. This will help to keep the project smaller and to avoid confusion as to what class or object you are supposed to be using. I always try to picture the next guy coming and working on my code and what he would think of and where he would stumble in my logic. I would only use a ViewModel if you are creating objects from multiple Models you retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I use only classes with get / set methods that operate a mapping of the DB and the VIEW. These are development policies. Using hybrid objects have a greater lightness of the project is in development at runtime. In some scenarios, there may be redundancy in the classes. It is important to aspire to the perfection of the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement it seems that you've created a duplicate data model which is mapped to a second model and would like to know if this is an optimal approach.

**Recommendation**

I don't think this is necessarily an optimal solution, but a lot depends on your use-case. What I typically do is create a data model that represents unique entities. Then I create a data management class that handles the interactions and use-cases of the data. The data manager would cover things like adding/removing custom objects from a collection. The approach I take is basically a lightweight approach to Apple's use of it's Core Data Framework ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)).

So for example one could use a dictionary, array, or set (or some combination of these) to manage the collection of custom objects together with a shared singleton object acting as a data manager and leveraging built-in archiving/unarchiving capabilities to handle a data graph requirements for an app. Actually,y the result is about the same as a simple use of Core Data, so I'd definitely recommend you get familiar with the standard approach used by Apple (it's embedded into every project template by default).

The good news is that once you choose an approach and develop it very carefully you could end up with a sharable resource that can be reused in many different projects. So for example, the data manager class might encapsulate the movement of data internally (files, local urls, etc) and externally (urls, soa, etc) and even deal with caching, serialization, etc.